# How to enable FTM(RTT) in android phone（ android version >= android 9）？

Tags: android, wifi, rtti

I write a simple app to check if the phone support ftm and check whether Wi-Fi RTT is available using a BroadcastReceiver.
**It return support and available!**.
Then I publish a service and configure ".serRangingEnabled(true)".

But the phone still doesn't support ftm. I capture its broadcast probe request packets and the related fields in Extended Capabilities don't set true(In unicast probe request packets ftm-initiator bit set ture ).  And my mobile phone doesn't response my ap's initial ftm request.
Why?

PS: In my test, AP is ftm initiating sta, and mobile phone is ftm responding sta.

Answer (score 0):

> > > PS: In my test, AP is ftm initiating sta, and mobile phone is ftm responding sta.

Android phones support Wi-Fi FTM RTT ranging with the phone being initiator (STA) and the access point being the responder (AP). How did you get an AP to be the initiator? (I am not sure how this would work, since the phone can't act as an AP and APs can't request FTM protocol).

Maybe you are referring to "Wi-FI Aware" method for communicating with neighboring devices? But there is no indication yet that someone has got this to support FTM RTT ranging.

For an Android app using IEEE 802.11mc see [FTMRTT](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.welwitschia.ftmrtt&hl=en_US&gl=US) and the [web page about FTMRTT](https://people.csail.mit.edu/bkph/FTMRTT_app).

For general information about using IEEE 802.11mc on Android see [FTM RTT](https://people.csail.mit.edu/bkph/ftmrtt) which includes links to videos and papers on the subject.